# How to create a media query that applies to all iPads in portrait?

Tags: html, css, ipad, media-queries

The problem is that the old iPad has 768 x 1024 px resolution while the new ones have 1536 x 2048 px resolution. How can I address bot iPads for portrait in one media query? Is this possible?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/device.css" media="only screen and (((min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1024px)) or ((min-width:1536px) and (max-width: 2048px)))">
```

I couldn't find examples where media query conditions are nested like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

see this [link](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/) hope it works for you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thanx for your valuable suggestion

Comment: Can someone explain what is the difference between using min-width: and min-device-width:? I assume min-device-width works for both non-retina and retina iPads?